# I can't seem to fix the dropdown codes in my html

Tags: html

I have recently been working on my sample website and wanted to enhance its functionality by incorporating multiple accordions. To achieve this, I turned to W3Schools and found a useful script or code that I copied and pasted into my project. However, I encountered an issue, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

Specifically, I would like to know the steps or modifications required to successfully incorporate multiple accordions into my website. Currently, the copied code only allows for a single accordion, but I desire the ability to include multiple accordions, each with its own set of content. This way, visitors to my website can access and interact with various sections or categories of information.

I hope you can provide me with guidance or instructions on how to achieve this desired functionality. I appreciate any assistance you can offer in helping me understand the necessary modifications or additions to the existing code. Thank you in advance for your support.

(https://imgur.com/a/QiMvaOe)

The issue I'm facing arises when I click on the 'Accommodation Rentals' accordion section. Instead of displaying its intended content, the 'Electronics Rentals' section unexpectedly pops up. To provide a clearer understanding of the problem, I have included a video demonstration in the link I shared.

My objective is to have distinct accordion sections on my website, each containing its own relevant content. For example, clicking on 'Accommodation Rentals' should expand that particular section, revealing information solely related to accommodation rentals. However, the current behavior contradicts this functionality.

I am unsure what modifications or adjustments are necessary to achieve the desired behavior. I would greatly appreciate any guidance, instructions, or suggested modifications to the existing code that can help me incorporate multiple accordions correctly.

Thank you for taking the time to review my request, and I look forward to any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. Your expertise and support are highly valued.

(HTML & CSS) https://codepen.io/Charles-Paul-Abanto/pen/QWZVjjJ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rent Em!</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="196x196" href="Logo/Logo.png">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .w3-sidebar a {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      }
      .logo {
        float: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative; right: 25px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .w3-padding-64 {
        padding-top: 1px!important;
        padding-bottom: 25px!important;
      }
      .fa {
        color: #ba3b0a;
      }
      .w3-left {
        color: #ba3b0a;
      }
      .w3-container {
        color: #ba3b0a;
      }
      body,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      .w3-wide {
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="w3-content" style="max-width: 1200px">
    <!-- Sidebar/menu -->
    <nav
      class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-white w3-collapse w3-top"
      style="z-index: 3; width: 250px"
      id="mySidebar"
    >
      <div class="w3-container w3-display-container w3-padding-16">
        <i
          onclick="w3_close()"
          class="fa fa-remove w3-hide-large w3-button w3-display-topright"
        ></i>
        <h3 class="w3-wide">
          <div class="logo">
          <b><img src="Logo/Rent Em Logo.png" height="160px" width="220px"/></b>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div
        class="w3-padding-64 w3-large w3-text-grey"
        style="font-weight: bold"
      >
      <a
          onclick="myAccFunc()"
          href="javascript:void(0)"
          class="w3-button w3-block w3-white w3-left-align"
          id="myBtn"
        >
          Electronics Rentals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div
          id="demoAcc"
          class="w3-bar-block w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium"
        >
          <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-light-grey"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Computers/Laptop</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Cameras.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Cameras</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Smartphones.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Smartphones</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Telivisions.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Telivisions</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Gaming Consoles.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Gaming Consoles</a
           >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Audio Equipment.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Audio Equipment</a
>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Accomodation Rentals</a>
        <div
        class="w3-padding-64 w3-large w3-text-grey"
        style="font-weight: bold"
      >
      <a
          onclick="myAccFunc()"
          href="javascript:void(0)"
          class="w3-button w3-block w3-white w3-left-align"
          id="charlespaul"
        >
          Accomodation Rentals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div
          id="demoAcc1"
          class="w3-bar-block w3-hide w3-padding-large w3-medium"
        >
          <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-light-grey"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Computer/Laptops</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Cameras.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Cameras</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Smartphones.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Smartphones</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Telivisions.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Telivisions</a
          >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Gaming Consoles.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Gaming Consoles</a
           >
          <a href="Hypertext References/Electronics/Audio Equipment.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"
            ><i class="fa fa-caret-right w3-margin-right"></i
            >Audio Equipment</a
>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vehicle Rentals</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Equipment Rentals</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Clothing Rentals</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Furniture Rentals</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Miscellaneous Rentals</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#footer" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding">Contact</a>
      <a
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"
        onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter').style.display='block'"
        >Newsletter</a
      >
      <a href="#footer" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding">Subscribe</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- Top menu on small screens -->
    <header class="w3-bar w3-top w3-hide-large w3-black w3-xlarge">
      <div class="w3-bar-item w3-padding-24 w3-wide">LOGO</div>
      <a
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-24 w3-right"
        onclick="w3_open()"
        ><i class="fa fa-bars"></i
      ></a>
    </header>

    <!-- Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens -->
    <div
      class="w3-overlay w3-hide-large"
      onclick="w3_close()"
      style="cursor: pointer"
      title="close side menu"
      id="myOverlay"
    ></div>

    <!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
    <div class="w3-main" style="margin-left: 250px">
      <!-- Push down content on small screens -->
      <div class="w3-hide-large" style="margin-top: 83px"></div>

      <!-- Top header -->
      <header class="w3-container w3-xlarge">
        <p class="w3-left"><b>Computers/Laptop</b></p>
        <p class="w3-right">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart w3-margin-right"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </p>
      </header>

      <div class="w3-container w3-text-grey" id="jeans">
        <p>8 items</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Product grid -->
      <div class="w3-row w3-grayscale">
        <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Acer Aspire 5.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Acer Aspire 5<br /><b>$24.99/Week</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Apple Macbook Air.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Apple Macbook Air<br /><b>$19.99/Week</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <div class="w3-display-container">
              <img src="Images/Computers Images/Asus ROG Strix Gaming Laptop.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
              <span class="w3-tag w3-display-topleft">New</span>
              <div class="w3-display-middle w3-display-hover">
                <button class="w3-button w3-black">
                  Rent now <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>Asus ROG Strix Gaming Laptop<br /><b>$19.99/Week</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Asus Vivobook 14.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Asus Vivobook 14<br /><b>$20.50/Week</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Dell Alienware.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Dell Alienware<br /><b>$20.50/Week</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <div class="w3-display-container">
              <img src="Images/Computers Images/Hp Chromebook.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
              <span class="w3-tag w3-display-topleft">Sale</span>
              <div class="w3-display-middle w3-display-hover">
                <button class="w3-button w3-black">
                  Rent now <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>HP Chromebook<br /><b class="w3-text-red">$14.99</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w3-col l3 s6">
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3<br /><b>$14.99</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="w3-container">
            <img src="Images/Computers Images/Samsung Galaxy Book.jfif" style="width: 100%" />
            <p>Samsung Galaxy Book<br /><b>$24.99</b></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Subscribe section -->
      <div class="w3-container w3-black w3-padding-32">
        <h1>Subscribe</h1>
        <p>To get future updates on special offers:</p>
        <p>
          <input
            class="w3-input w3-border"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter e-mail"
            style="width: 100%"
          />
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-red w3-margin-bottom">
          Subscribe
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer
        class="w3-padding-64 w3-light-grey w3-small w3-center"
        id="footer"
      >
        <div class="w3-row-padding">
          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <p>Questions? Go ahead.</p>
            <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank">
              <p>
                <input
                  class="w3-input w3-border"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="Name"
                  required
                />
              </p>
              <p>
                <input
                  class="w3-input w3-border"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="Email"
                  required
                />
              </p>
              <p>
                <input
                  class="w3-input w3-border"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Subject"
                  name="Subject"
                  required
                />
              </p>
              <p>
                <input
                  class="w3-input w3-border"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Message"
                  name="Message"
                  required
                />
              </p>
              <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-block w3-black">
                Send
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="w3-col s4">
            <h4>About</h4>
            <p><a href="#">About us</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">We're hiring</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Support</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Find store</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Shipment</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Payment</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Gift card</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Return</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Help</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="w3-col s4 w3-justify">
            <h4>Store</h4>
            <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i> Charles Paul A. Abanto</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> +649569029435</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> charlespaulaabanto@mabinicolleges.edu.ph</p>
            <h4>We accept</h4>
            <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cc-amex"></i> Gcash</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-credit-card"></i> Paymaya</p>
            <br />
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-snapchat w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity w3-large"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>


      <!-- End page content -->
    </div>

    <!-- Newsletter Modal -->
    <div id="newsletter" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom" style="padding: 32px">
        <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
          <i
            onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter').style.display='none'"
            class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge"
          ></i>
          <h2 class="w3-wide">NEWSLETTER</h2>
          <p>
            Join our mailing list to receive updates on new arrivals and special
            offers.
          </p>
          <p>
            <input
              class="w3-input w3-border"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter e-mail"
            />
          </p>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-red w3-margin-bottom"
            onclick="document.getElementById('newsletter').style.display='none'"
          >
            Subscribe
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Accordion
      function myAccFunc() {
        var x = document.getElementById("demoAcc1");
        if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
          x.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
          x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
      }

        // Accordion
        function myAccFunc() {
        var y = document.getElementById("demoAcc");
        if (y.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
          y.className += " w3-show";
        } else {
          y.className = y.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
        }
      }

      // Click on the "Jeans" link on page load to open the accordion for demo purposes
      document.getElementById("myBtn").click();

      // Open and close sidebar
      function w3_open() {
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
      }

      function w3_close() {
        document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your actual code as text, not pictures of your code.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Sorry about that, I forgot. I just added it, thank you!

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet that can be run in the question. You may need to add the correct styles for it as well since there is no accordion styling.  In the future please include **all code** needed to make your example work so that people can help you.  Photos of text and unstyled HTML make it near impossible for anyone to help you.  A working demo is much easier to work with than a cell phone recording of your monitor.

Comment: @charlespaulabanto you might be having CSS or using a library. Please add the CSS and `<link>` to library if you have. Also please edit tags if you are using a library so that it will get more attention from people familiar with that library.

Comment: @FiniteLooper I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience caused. As I am currently in the process of learning, my knowledge about coding and related subjects is quite limited. I'm aware that I still have much to learn in this area, and I appreciate your understanding and patience with me.

Comment: @ADasGH I am using CSS and have recently made some edits to the post. To link the CSS, I utilized codepen.io.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for `<link>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some overall recommendations to you because you have a few problems and some of these might be causing your issue, but in general they are good pracice anyway since I know you are still learning.

- You have a few spelling errors, not a code issue but just something to be aware of.  `Accomodation` should be `Accommodation` and `Telivisions` should be `Televisions`
- You are using styles all over the place. You have some in external CSS files, some in `<style>` tags, and some inline on elements with `style=""` attributes.  I highly recommend moving all styles into an external CSS file. This makes everything much easier to manage in the future since all styles are in one place and you don't have to go hunting around for something.

My suggestion is that you consolidate your CSS into multiple files (maybe one for navigation, one for main page stuff, and another for "helper" classes?).

---

It looks like you have a few HTML errors, some are minor but some might be the cause of your issue.  There are a few places where you have closed nested tags in the wrong order.  Copy all of your HTML and paste it into this tool and it will tell you the problems.

#### https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Keep reading below for my take on how to fix the big issues, but I recommend you then come back to this tool afterwards and try to fix the minor HTML validation issues too.

---

The big issues are the unclosed tags, which are all in your sidebar/navigation area. This is an easy thing to make a mistake on, but it can cause a lot of issues.

The first one is here:

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-display-container w3-padding-16">
  <i onclick="w3_close()"
     class="fa fa-remove w3-hide-large w3-button w3-display-topright"></i>
  <h3 class="w3-wide">
    <div class="logo">
      <b><img src="Logo/Rent Em Logo.png" height="160px" width="220px"/></b>
  </h3>
</div>
```

There are a few issues here.
First, the element that begins `<div class="logo">` has no closing tag!  This will most likely cascade errors down the document.  A closing `</div>` is needed somewhere

But next up is that you are not allowed to place a `<div>` inside of an `<h3>` tag.  That's a block level element inside of a text element.  You should either change this to be a `<span>` or just remove that element all together and put that `class="logo"` on the `<b>` tag, or even remove that and place that class right on the `<img` tag since `<b>` really isn't doing anything here. That simplifies things a lot.

In that `<img` tag you are setting `height="160px" width="220px"`, but you should only be putting numbers in here and not `px` units.  In face a much better way to do this is to set the size in your CSS instead of here in the HTML.  You already have a CSS class for the logo anyway, so you might as well use that for controlling the size as well.

So here's my recommendation for the changes for this area.  Move the image sizes to the CSS and change the HTML to be as follows

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-display-container w3-padding-16">
  <i onclick="w3_close()"
     class="fa fa-remove w3-hide-large w3-button w3-display-topright"></i>
  <h3 class="w3-wide">
    <img class="logo" src="Logo/Rent Em Logo.png"/>
  </h3>
</div>
```

---

Next is inside of your `<nav>` element.  There is a closing `</div>` tag missing on something inside of here.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's the closing tag for  `<div class="w3-padding-64 w3-large w3-text-grey" style="font-weight: bold">` that is missing.  Do this: Add a closing `</div>` tag right before your "Contacts" link near the end of the `<nav>` element, like this:

```html
</div>
<a href="#footer" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding">Contact</a>
```

---

For the accordion, first I want to make a recommendation: Move your inline `<script>` JS into a file and link to it. It becomes much easier to manage this way

Now, the problem you are having is actually a very simple one.  I know you said you are new to programming so I'll try to explain it.  You have the function `myAccFunc` defined twice. Both seem to be copy/paste identical except for the ID that's being selected inside of them.  Since both functions have the exact same name, when you are clicking on an accordion to call the function it just picks one of them and uses that for both.  One way to fix this would to rename one of the functions and then each accordion calls a different function, but there's a better way

Replace both of those functions with this:

```js
 // Accordion
function myAccFunc(accordionId) {
  var x = document.getElementById(accordionId);
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
  }
}
```

So just one function and each time you use it you pass in the ID of the element you want to expand/collapse.  So now you'd use it like this:

`<a onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc')"` and `<a onclick="myAccFunc('demoAcc1')"`

---

I hope all of this helps you!  Here is a codepen of all of these changes I mentioned: https://codepen.io/FiniteLooper/pen/MWPqoLw